# Redefining a Deleted Package (Common Lisp)

Tags: package, common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I’m using `delete-package` as a simple way to unintern a lot of old (user specified) variable names, before loading a project back in following certain edits to the package files.  (Otherwise, new values can get `push`ed onto the old values for those variable names defined by the end-user.)  But SBCL complains when I try to reload after the deletion.

After one-time loading an `init.lisp` file which sets up Quicklisp, ASDF, and installs some Quicklisp libraries, I then load the project with `(progn (asdf:load-system “my-project”) (in-package :my-package))`, where the project definition `my-project.asd` file contains

```
(when (find-package :my-package)
  (delete-package :my-package))

(defpackage :my-package
  (:use :cl))

(asdf:defsystem "my-project"
   …)
```

This all works fine on the first load, but stumbles on the second load of the project, because

`*PACKAGE* can't be a deleted package:
    It has been reset to #<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">.`

Where is the error coming from?  Can it be fixed, retaining the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate package to hold the user-defined symbols, say `(defpackage :us)` in addition to the working package. `(:use :cl)` is not required since the package contains only data. Install the user symbols using `(in-package :us)` when loading the user files, `intern` into `:us` programmatically, or direct reference with the package prefix. Access the symbols with the package prefix. The `(delete-package :us)` should then work.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally SBCL can delete and recreate packages with the same name.  The error message indicates that the current package (`*PACKAGE*`) has been deleted.  Try to assure that the current package is a different package, e.g. CL-USER, when deleting your package.